# find a component that contains a certain class name react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, classname

Find the Component from a list of components that contains a certain class name.
In my case i want to show the component that has the className "bbb". But I can't seem to find the className. In the code below i made my example with the Name of the component just so I can demonstrate better what i want to achieve:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Test = () => {

  const One = () => {
    return (
      <h1 className='aaa' >one</h1>
    )
  }
  const Two = () => {
    return (
      <h1 className='bbb' >two</h1>
    )
  }
  const Three = () => {
    return (
      <h1 className='ccc' >Three</h1>
    )
  }

  const [data, setdata] = useState([<One />, <Two />, <Three />])

  return (
    <section>
      {data.filter(x => x.type.name === 'One').map(x => {
      // something like this line below. This doesn't work of course
      // {data.filter(x => x.classList.contains('bbb)).map(x => {
        return <div>{x}</div>
      })}
    </section>
  )
};

export default Test;
```

I am really new to React js so sorry if this is a stupid question.

Edit: Fixed a typo

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding a class name for that filter, you can do it this way.

2 key things in my changes:

`const [data, setdata] = useState([One, Two, Three])` You should not call `<One/>` (under the hook, it's calling `React.createElement(One)` to render that component)

`data.filter((Component) => Component === Two)` Check the component reference instead of class name, because class name may be changed and it will cause a bug in your logic

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Test = () => {
  const One = () => {
    return <h1 className="aaa">one</h1>
  }
  const Two = () => {
    return <h1 className="bbb">two</h1>
  }
  const Three = () => {
    return <h1 className="ccc">Three</h1>
  }

  const [data, setdata] = useState([One, Two, Three])

  return (
    <section>
      {data
        .filter((Component) => Component === Two)
        .map((Component) => {
          return (
            <div>
              <Component />
            </div>
          )
        })}
    </section>
  )
}

export default Test
```

Comment: In my case I really need to find the className, but thanks for suggesting this.

Comment: Another case I also want to mention, `x.classList.contains('bbb')` does not work because `x` is presenting for `<One/>` which is the parent of the actual element having the class name `bbb`. If it is `<One className="bbb" />`, you may be able to find it. In your example, if you want to look for class name in children components, you need to do this `x.props.children` to access all children data and then you can look for `bbb` from children.

Comment: By the way, could I get an upvote from you? That really encourages me to help Stackoverflow's community :D @HappyCoconut

Comment: @HappyCoconut you need to rethink how you're approaching this problem. React (a library) has a very specific approach to how it updates the DOM. You maybe asking the wrong question.